# How to link bokeh widget parameters with cb_obj.get() in js callbacks

Tags: bokeh

I've been looking over the bokeh doc page on [Adding interactions](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#javascript-callbacks) and am *completely* mystified as to how parameters from widgets are passed to the cb_obj.get() function in javascript callbacks.

I can't understand how the arguments to the cb_obj.get() function are chosen, e.g.:

- cb_obj.get('value')
- cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices
- cb_obj.get('data')
- cb_obj.get('start')
- cb_obj.get('end')

The arguments seem to look like standard terms, but I can't see where they are defined.

Comment: Actually, I worked it out.  The input arguments for the cb_obj.get() function can be found from inspecting the properties of the widget that was target of the js callback. , e.g. for a widget called 'slider' use vars(slider) to see its properties.

Comment: This will reveal all of the sliders properties, including the 'value' property which stores the slider value. Would be good though if the bokeh widget output properties were enunciated in the documentation.

Comment: can you provide a code example?